# Can't use Brother MFC-J625DW scanner as normal user

Tags: drivers, permissions, scanner, brother

I have installed Brothers Linux drivers from their website and the printer function seems to work but the scanner function will not. Running Simple Scan I get the error: Unable to connect to scanner. My printer/scanner is USB connected. Ubuntu MATE 14.10 64 bit.

I have noticed I can run the scanner using sudo so I am guessing I have a permissions issue.

The question here is how to allow a normal user to run my scanner without elevated privileges.

I've put some outputs from my troubleshooting below.

lusb shows:

```
    Bus 002 Device 003: ID 05e3:0716 Genesys Logic, Inc. USB 2.0 Multislot Card Reader/Writer
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 003: ID 06a3:0728 Saitek PLC 
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 1532:0034 Razer USA, Ltd 
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 1058:0704 Western Digital Technologies, Inc. Passport External HDD
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f9:0282 Brother Industries, Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

sane-find-scanner:

```
    # sane-find-scanner will now attempt to detect your scanner. If the
  # result is different from what you expected, first make sure your
  # scanner is powered up and properly connected to your computer.

  # No SCSI scanners found. If you expected something different, make sure that
  # you have loaded a kernel SCSI driver for your SCSI adapter.

could not fetch string descriptor: Pipe error
could not fetch string descriptor: Pipe error
found USB scanner (vendor=0x04f9 [Brother], product=0x0282 [MFC-J625DW]) at libusb:001:003
  # Your USB scanner was (probably) detected. It may or may not be supported by
  # SANE. Try scanimage -L and read the backend's manpage.

  # Not checking for parallel port scanners.

  # Most Scanners connected to the parallel port or other proprietary ports
  # can't be detected by this program.
```

dpkg -l | grep Brother

```
ii  brscan-skey                                 0.2.4-1                                  amd64        Brother Linux scanner S-KEY tool
ii  brscan4                                     0.4.2-1                                  amd64        Brother Scanner Driver
ii  mfcj625dwcupswrapper                        3.0.0-1                                  i386         Brother CUPS Inkjet Printer Definitions
ii  mfcj625dwlpr                                3.0.1-1                                  i386         Brother lpr Inkjet Printer Definitions
ii  printer-driver-brlaser                      3-3                                      amd64        printer driver for (some) Brother laser printers
ii  printer-driver-ptouch                       1.3-8                                    amd64        printer driver Brother P-touch label printers
```

Answer (score 0):

So I cannot test this as no access to USB scanner but I have seen a group in `/etc/groups` called `scanner`

can you try adding a user to this group then logout and back in as that user and test?

```
sudo usermod -a -G scanner usernamehere
```

Comment: I followed your instructions to the letter and did a reboot. Both my accounts are now in the "scanner" group but I still get the same error and can only use the scanner by invoking sudo.

Answer (score 0):

As a solution, Brother provides a `.deb` package which can be downloaded [here](http://www.brother.com/pub/bsc/linux/dlf/brother-udev-rule-type1-1.0.0-1.all.deb). It can be installed by clicking on the file or with the following command:

```
dpkg -i brother-udev-rule-type1-1.0.0-1.all.deb
```